# Manually installing laravel/ui results in error

Tags: php, laravel, raspberry-pi, laravel-7, laravel-ui

I'm trying to install the Laravel/ui package into an existing Laravel 7.28.4 project. I've installed the package on my local machine and uploaded the vendor/laravel/ui and vendor/composer folder manually to the remote server. I've done it this way because my server is a Raspberry PI 3 Model B with 1GB of RAM, composer ran out of memory when I tried installing the package. When I open the website or run any "php artisan" command (On the remote server), I get this error:

> RuntimeException
> In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If composer is running out of memory, try running with the memory limit flag.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

You also need to run:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried delete .php files within bootstrap/cache folder?
[Laravel 8 UI issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926228/laravel-8-ui-issue)
I follow watercayman comment its work for me